# How does Record locking behave in master-detail-sub-detail hierarchy?

Tags: master-detail, locking

In the ERD below all the objects are linked by MDR.

If I update a record in `detail 3` I understand that `detail 2` would get locked. Would `detail 1` and `master` get locked as well?

How would I test this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the [record locking cheat sheet](https://d259t2jj6zp7qm.cloudfront.net/images/20210727114613/SF_Record-Locking-Cheatsheet_web-1.pdf)?

Comment: [Avoiding Deadlocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_deadlocks.htm) mentions that Apex locks parent records, then children, in ascending Id order. There's no mention if this lock extends to grandparent records or higher, but I think it'd be safe to assume that it must, because the parent of the child is itself a child.

Comment: I guess there no easy way to test this out because these locks in the DB will occur only for a very short duration. Plus, Salesforce will have it own optimization at platform level to efficiently manage the record locking duration (this makes it challenging to test out the behaviour). But if you were to play around large data volume, you may be able to test this out. However, I would assume that the lock behaviour extends all the way to topmost parent, otherwise salesforce would be risking serious data referential integrity issues.